# Passing parameters to popup window?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to pass parameters to a popup window via query string(a hidden field id & a textbox id). However, since I am using master pages the id's are very long (ct100_someid). Is there a way to elegantly pass my ids ?Can I shorten my id's or not show them to the user at all ? Please tell me any alternates.

Comment: how will you be using ids on popup? put some value in those fields or read something from them?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There will grid of items on my popup window of which a user may select one, it would then close the popup window and set the textbox field & hidden field value on parent page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define function on parent page which can be accessed by popup window to set values of fiedls:

On parent page

```
function setHiddenValues(a,b,c){
    document.getElementById("<%= hiddenField1.ClientID%>").value = a;
    document.getElementById("<%= hiddenField2.ClientID%>").value = b;
    document.getElementById("<%= hiddenField3.ClientID%>").value = c;
}
```

On popup page, after user selects row:

```
parent.setHiddenValues(val1, val2, val3);
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to encrypt the querystring so the curious user doesn't feel compelled to try replacing `?CustID=1&etc` with `?CustID=2&etc` for example. This is just for convenience as I also do a check in the code behind to make sure the customer looking at the page is authenticated, but IMHO looks more professional. See [here](http://devcity.net/Articles/47/1/encrypt_querystring.aspx) for an example in vb.net.

To pass a shorter name you can also use jquery to select the hidden field using the id attribute rather than the whole client ID,

eg : 
`<asp:net HiddenField id="hdnName" runat="server" />`

`var hiddenfield = $("element[id$=_hdnName]");`

Comment: It might not be my requirement now but the explanation and approach is very informative. +1