# Pass the value from popup window to parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing parameters to popup window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075296/passing-parameters-to-popup-window)

I created Parent window and when i click on button popup window will appear.In popup window two drop down list are there.i have to take the list values from master table and populate in first drop down list on this basis of first, second drop down list will populate the value from its own table.when i click to go button it will show the result in data grid table in every row select hyperlink will present so after selecting it's result will populate in parent window and popup will close.

Comment: try `window.opener`, if you can access it, then you can setup value or call function from it

Comment: What are you asking for?

Comment: this is covered in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075296/passing-parameters-to-popup-window

Comment: actually also in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867289/popup-window-return-value

Answer (score 0):

[window.opener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp) is the way to achieve this functionality.